# How to do a login system properly?

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js

I'm using node, express and passport. I want to implement a custom registration form and login for users that don't have a Google account. The question is, how do I do it securely?

How much do I have to implement myself? I assume that I should keep user's usernames and hashed passwords (which hashing algorithm should I use?) in the database and then compare the pair sent by the client with the pair in the database.

Now, how do I securely transmit the hash to the server? I know the trick with locks that maybe can be applied here so tell me if this would work (and if it's indeed what I should do).

Hash the password on the client, generate a random number and rotate each byte in the hash by that number (this should definitely be replaced by a better technique that takes a random key and encrypts data). Then send that to the server. The server does the same, generate a number, rotate. Server sends that back to the client. The client "unrotates" the string and returns it to the server. The server "unrotates" the string.

The result will be the original hash.

The obvious weakness here is the rotation. If someone is looking at the messages, they can very easily determine the rotation number of both the server and the client.

I know very little about security but I would like to learn. Do I actually need to do any of this if I use a library like passport?

Comment: Don't bother with the rotation. It's complicated and doesn't give you anything. Just post the password as clear text over SSL.

Comment: Is it really that simple? How do I do it?

Comment: Also, isn't it a bad idea to keep passwords as plaintext on the server?

Comment: You know, the regular HTML `<form>` with `<input type="password">`. And make it post to a https url. Details on how to set up SSL in node.js you can search in the internets. :)

Comment: No-no, I said only "transmit password as plain text". On the server, hash it with per-user salt and store the hash. Never store plain text password.

Comment: Wow... I was really overcomplicating the whole thing.

Comment: SSL does the encryption, so it isn't in plain text when you SSL it. It's just that SSL takes care of making it not-plain-text for you.